# Retain Cycle when annotating member with @ObservedObject in SubView used as destination in NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using an `@ObservedObject` member inside a SubView that is used as the destination of a NavigationLink, that class is never deallocated.

Example:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        Text("row \(i)")
                        NavigationLink(destination: SubView()) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("bar")
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        print("init - \(String(describing: type(of: self)))")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit - \(String(describing: type(of: self)))")
    }
}
```

Going back and forth the navigation stack will produce as many instances of ViewModel in this case.

Memory Graph:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 14 this can be fixed by annotating `viewModel` with `@StateObject` instead.

When using `@ObservedObject` you'll notice that ViewModel is initialised when constructing the ParentView.
When using `@StateObject` ViewModel is initialised only once you navigate to SubView.

---

In iOS 13 you will most likely have to have Bindings in your SubView or use an `@EnvironmentObject` that is shared between all your SubViews to break the retain cycle since `@StateObject` was introduced in iOS 14.

---

What is the reason?

I'm assuming Apple introduced @StateObject to address this problem and to make it clear to the compiler that the class member should be deallocated when the owning struct is removed from memory.